# Multi-Conditional WHERE Clause In CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to delete some data like this query that is in core PHP

```
WHERE user_id=$id AND sender_id=$send_id OR user_id=$send_id AND sender_id=$id
```

So I tried it in CodeIgniter using Active Record like this :

```
$this->db->where('user_id ', $id);
$this->db->or_where('user_id ', $send_id);
$this->db->where('sender_id ', $send_id);
$this->db->or_where('sender_id ', $id);
```

But it gives me the wrong result. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$this->db->where(array('user_id' => $id, 'sender_id' => $send_id));
$this->db->or_where(array('user_id' => $send_id, 'sender_id' => $id));
```

You want to pass an associative array to each one, where it will use `AND` between each element in array in query, and using the `->or_where()` will use an `OR` in the query. More info is available in the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html).

Comment: thanks both answrs works for me bt i like this one because it's easy to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
    $this->db->where('user_id ', $id);
    $this->db->where('sender_id ', $send_id);

    $this->db->or_where('sender_id ', $id);
    $this->db->where('user_id ', $send_id);
```